# azure command line tool for linux machine to upload/download data to/from Azure Storage

Tags: linux, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for azure command line tool in linux. I found azure-cli, but its not supporting upload and download feature in azure storage (As per my knowledge).

I found some CLI tools but those are running only on windows. those are

- AzCopy
- cloudcopy

So can anybody suggest one best azure CLI tool, which can run on linux machine and able to perform upload and download operations??

It would be great if that supports partial read and partial write.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's support for upload and download :

```
azure storage blob upload [options] [file] [container] [blob]
azure storage blob download [options] [container] [blob] [destination]
```

If not seeing them try to update your cli tools first:

```
npm install azure-cli -g
```

(Node.js must be installed in your system)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

A little late to this question, but hopefully this will help anyone looking for an answer. The Azure Batch and HPC team has released a code sample with some [AzCopy-like functionality on Python called blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer). [full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code]

Comment: Awesome! 
BTW is there any example on how to authenticate using blobxfer?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix authentication parameters together. `--subscriptionid` must be paired with `--managementcert`. If you're using a shared storage account key then neither of those are required, just use `--storageaccountkey` with the actual storage key text (not a pem file). If using a sas key then just supply `--saskey`.

Comment: Figured it out, what confused me was that you need to supply the key in base64 and not just storage text. A string that ends with "==" usually. I kept getting "incorrect padding" python errors.

Comment: Great tool for MAC users as an alternative to AzCopy. This is the full command I used to upload all the files and folder in the directory to a container: `sudo blobxfer $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT --storageaccountkey=$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY $container_name $path_to_upload --upload --include '**/**'`

Answer (score 1):

if the above doesn help, you might also be able to install the latest version through elevated privileges like this
sudo npm instal azure-cli -g

Answer (score 1):

Azure CLI 2.0 which is python based release supporting ARM based deployment can be used to download the blob storage contents one by one. Here is the step by step guide for the same - http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.in/2017/03/how-to-download-azure-blob-storage.html

However you can't download the all the blob from a container in one go. Cli does not support it as of today.